# define EntityAttachment for baseEntity in order to integrate all files in one table in database

Tags: entity-framework, boilerplate, aspnetboilerplate

i designed a new solution based on asp.net boilerplate module-zero and i need to store attachment files that related to each entity(each row of table) in separate table in database. basically i must assumed a new entity which relate to other entity with navigation property and this approach means that each time i design new entity in this solution i have to reference it to attachment entity so i decided to design a better solution for this particular problem. i want to create a Base Class or interface for Attachment Entity named "IEntityAttachment" or "EntityAttachment" and this means that Entity class must derived from this interface or class.
the question is "is this approach possible?" and "what is the best approach for this problem?"

First Approach :
[image: First Approach]

Second Approach(that i want):

[image: Second Approach]

Comment: Show relevant code and expected usage.

Comment: thanks. i completed my question.

Comment: It's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: i have no idea that how implementation looks like for second approach. can you help me with example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that approach is possible.

First, define `EntityAttachment` and `Attachment` classes.

```
public abstract class EntityAttachment : Entity {}

public class Attachment : EntityAttachment
{
    // ...
}
```

Next, define `BaseEntity` classes to reference above classes:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity<TEntityAttachment> : Entity
    where TEntityAttachment : EntityAttachment
{
    public virtual int AttachmentId { get; set; }

    public virtual TEntityAttachment Attachment { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseEntity : BaseEntity<Attachment> {}
```

Then, define the `Article`, `News` and `Slider` classes:

```
public class Article : BaseEntity
{
    // ...
}

public class News : BaseEntity
{
    // ...
}

public class Slider : BaseEntity
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. and is there any way for modify asp.net boilerplate module-zero predefined "BaseEntity" or "FullAuditEntity" and add new property like AttachmentId or ...?
if answer is "no" where can i define and implement these classes in Abp structure?

Comment: Why would you do that? Just define the entities like I described above.

Comment: of course, but i have a problem with place of code. i assumed BaseEntity class in abp.core  project. but i have no idea where is best place in solution to define this class as a parent class.

Comment: You can define them in your `.Core` project, create an `Entities` folder.

Comment: thanks a lot. and what about "FullAuditedEntity" ?  can i change "BaseEntity" with "FullAuditedEntity" for auditing in this solution?

Comment: You can make `BaseEntity<TEntityAttachment>` inherit `FullAuditedEntity`.